# How to avoid string could not be parsed as xml error?

Tags: php, xml

My code is parsing xml using `SimpleXMLElement` class as shown below

```
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response, LIBXML_ERR_ERROR, false, 'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11');
```

The xml data is provided by one of the AWS services.

Very frequently I encounter "String Could not be parsed as XML" error which causes the script to terminate. How do you get the script to ignore this error and keep running?

As I have said earlier, the xml data is provided by API and I don't have any control over the contents of the xml data. Is there a way to validate the data before I instantiate the class?

Comment: Wrap in `try-catch`?

Comment: How about a try-catch with a retry mechanism?

Comment: Are you sure its safe to continue processing the file in these situations?

Comment: Would be good to see the code, maybe you are doing something that is contribution to this error, or maybe just not checking something before attempting to process it

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for your concerns but I am using the code provided by AWIS service from AWS (without much modification). It is very poorly written in my opinion. The worst thing that can happen by ignoring this error is that the script will not write data to mysql table for that particular search term which is completely fine with me. I just don't want the script to quit on me. If you want I can still post the whole code.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post code.

Comment: try catch works. Thanks u_mulder and Luis

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any control over the contents of the xml data

Yes, you do. You have the whole response in a variable as a string, you can process it any way you fancy.

Start with logging responses that trigger the error. Then get one from the logs and run the `new SimpleXmlElement` part in a separate php file on the input. If it fails, you know that the data is at fault. Remove half of the data and run the parser again. If it passes, restore the deleted part and remove another. If it fails, go on narrowing down the data until you reach to the root of evil.

It often happens on poorly written xml providers that they put html entities in xml files without declaring them, or they don't escape apostrophes when they have to, etc.

If you discover this is the case, you can run a `str_replace` to fix the xml before parsing.

This is sad reality which goes against all the neatly written w3c standards, but sometimes you have to go a dirty path to make it work. Cheers!

Comment: Your point is well taken. But I needed a quick and dirty solution. `try-catch` does exactly that. Thanks for your input. If I have time in future, I will try to decipher the xml and find the root cause(s),

Answer (score 1):

Don't refer to it as XML data. Refer to it as non-XML data. That helps to establish the right mindset. When you talk to the supplier of this data, don't let them be under any illusion that they are delivering XML. Your life would be much easier if they did deliver XML, and you need to make sure they know this.

If it isn't XML, and you still want to parse it (rather than simply returning it to sender as unfit for purpose), then you need to know what it actually is. There's no way any program can parse data whose syntax is completely unpredictable. You need to find out in what ways it differs from XML, then you're going to have to find some strategy for repairing it where it's broken, which you can only do if you develop some kind of understanding of the nature of its brokenness. For example if the problem is lack of quotes around attribute values, then your strategy will be quite different from handling unmatched element tags.

Comment: Michael, I agree with you. However,  one does not expect this from AWS It is one of those much neglected service (Alexa Web Information Service) by Amazon AWS. Up until now, we could not even access the service without the IAM root keys (which is a big NO NO from Amazon's own security guidelines). I had to open a separate AWS account to use this service just to keep rest of my infrastructure secure. I think it is one of those acquisitions which Amazon should not have done. The only thing that they have done with this acquisition is stolen the "Alexa" name for their personal virtual assistant.